# Why does this NSDate gotten from NSString have the month switched?

Tags: ios, nsdate

Im sending a string to a dateFormatter with this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm a"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CST"]];

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar* calendario = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [calendario components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];

//make new strings
NSString *adjustedOpenDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%ld-%ld %@", @"2013", (long)[components month], (long)[components day], openDateString];
NSString *adjustedCloseDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%ld-%ld %@", @"2013", (long)[components month], (long)[components day],closeDateString];
NSLog(@"adjustedString %@", adjustedCloseDateString);  //<<<<---NSLOG1

//Convert strings to dates
NSDate *openDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:adjustedOpenDateString];
NSDate *closeDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:adjustedCloseDateString];

NSLog(@"BEFORE COMPONENTS open, now, close %@,%@,%@", openDate,[NSDate date], closeDate); //<<<<---NSLOG2

if ([self timeCompare:openDate until:closeDate]) {
    NSLog(@"OPEN-timeCompare");
} else {
    NSLog(@"CLOSED-timeCompare");
}
```

And I get the adjustedString NSLog logging the current date correctly:

```
adjustedString 2013-7-25 10:00 PM
```

But when I log the dates converted from strings, the month is lost...switched from july to jan

```
open, now, close 2013-01-25 13:00:00 +0000,2013-07-26 02:54:31 +0000,2013-01-26 04:00:00 +0000
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your format string to `@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"` According to the [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns), which NSDateFormatter uses for date format strings, lowercase 'm' is for minute and uppercase is for month.

Answer (score 3):

Your format string is wrong, for month you have to use "MM", so replace:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm a"];
```

with

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];
```

Take a look at [Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns), Unicode Technical Standard #35.